# split serial string -msp430+processing

Tags: string, serial-port, processing, msp430

I am another newbie, trying to finish an assignment, and I would need some help in splitting a string from serial.

I use the demo code for eZ430-RF2500 Wireless Sensor Monitor, where I changed only the tx of the access point's temperature(by commenting it), with the purpose of displaying only the temperature of the remote sensor.

The string is in the following form: `Node:0001, Temp:28.1C, Battery:2.6V, Strenght:031%, RE:no`

The processing code for the above displayed string:

```
import processing.serial.*;

Serial myPort;

String sensorReading="";

void setup() {

size(800,600);

myPort = new Serial(this, "COM7", 9600);

myPort.bufferUntil('\n');

}

void draw() {

//The serialEvent controls the display

}

void serialEvent (Serial myPort){

sensorReading = myPort.readStringUntil('\n');

if(sensorReading != null){

sensorReading=trim(sensorReading);

}

writeText("Sensor Reading: " + sensorReading);

}

void writeText(String textToWrite){

background(255);

fill(0);

text(textToWrite, width/20, height/2);

}
```

I would need to split the string in this way:

```
Node:0001

Temp:28.1C

Battery:2.6V

Strenght:031%

RE:no
```

I tried some examples using an array with (splitTokens(sensorReading, ",")), charAt(), but the println() does not seem to work,I got the error `disabling serialevent() for com null.`

Would anyone suggest me how can I solve this?

Thank you.

Have a good day.

Comment: Your question is about splitting a String, so you don't need to include any of the other stuff. Start by posting this code:
void setup(){
 String str = "Node:0001, Temp:28.1C, Battery:2.6V, Strenght:031%, RE:no"; 
}

Then add what you've tried to split the String to that code, along with the errors you're receiving.

Comment: @George Profenza gives you a really good  answer on how to splitt a string. But your error message mentioned Com null. Are you sure you assigned the hardware to COM7. Please have a look into the device manager.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to easily replace commas with new line characters:

```
String fromSerial = "Node:0001, Temp:28.1C, Battery:2.6V, Strenght:031%, RE:no";
println(fromSerial.replace(", ","\n"));
```

Splitting and joining should also work:

```
String fromSerial = "Node:0001, Temp:28.1C, Battery:2.6V, Strenght:031%, RE:no";
println(join(fromSerial.split(", "),"\n"));
```

You should be able to parse the data once you split it as well:

```
String fromSerial = "Node:0001, Temp:28.1C, Battery:2.6V, Strenght:031%, RE:no";
String[] data = fromSerial.split(", ");
try{
  for(String s : data){
    String[] entry = s.split(":");
    String label = entry[0];
    float value = 0;
    if(label.equals("Node")) value = float(entry[1].substring(0));
    //etc. 
  }
}catch(Exception e){
  println("error parsing data");
}
```

The `try...catch` block should help prevent that `disabling serialEvent()` error message which usually happens when you have errors while processing serial data in that function.

Aside from splitting the string, I'd recommend processing the string if it's not null:

```
if (sensorReading != null) {

    sensorReading=trim(sensorReading);
    writeText("Sensor Reading: " + sensorReading);
  }
```

**Quick update**
In terms of parsing, if you need to save the data, you can actually easily place the value in a JSON object:

```
String fromSerial = "Node:0001, Temp:28.1C, Battery:2.6V, Strenght:031%, RE:no";
String[] values = fromSerial.split(", ");
try{
  JSONObject data = new JSONObject();

  for(String s : values){
    String[] entry = s.split(":");
    String label = entry[0];
    int lastCharIndex = entry[1].length();

    if(label.equals("Node")) data.setInt(label,int(entry[1]));
    if(label.equals("Temp")) data.setFloat(label,float(entry[1].substring(0,lastCharIndex-1)));
    if(label.equals("Battery")) data.setFloat(label,float(entry[1].substring(0,lastCharIndex-1)));
    if(label.equals("Strenght")) data.setInt(label,int(entry[1].substring(0,lastCharIndex-1)));
    if(label.equals("RE")) data.setBoolean(label,entry[1].toLowerCase().equals("yes"));


  }

  println(data);
  saveJSONObject(data,year() + nf(month(),2) + nf(day(),2) + "-"  + nf(hour(),2) + nf(minute(),2) + nf(second(),2)+".json");

}catch(Exception e){
  println("error parsing data");
}
```

This is a basic example, you'd add data entries to a [JSONArray](https://processing.org/reference/JSONArray.html) and save multiple entries in a file as opposed to many files with a single data entry each.

Comment: I used `replaceAll("," , "\n") `, thank you so much for all the info. !

Comment: No worries, feel free to vote/mark the answer if it was useful ;)